# $r\mapsto \max_{|z|\leq r}|f(z)|$ is strictly increasing if $f$ not constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a **continuous** function, and define $M_f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ by $M_f(r)=\max_{|z|\leq r}|f(z)|$. Then clearly $M_f$ is increasing.

Is it true that $M_f$ is strictly increasing, if $f$ is not constant? I was thinking about Liouville's theorem, but it is for entire functions.

Comment: Your assumption "continuous" is not enough.  To get a genuine theorem, assume, for example, $f$ is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider for example
$$
f(z) = \begin{cases} |z| & |z| \leq 1 \\ 1 & |z| \geq 1 \end{cases}.
$$
Then $M_f(r) = 1$ for all $r\geq1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true: for example, consider $f(z)=\max(|z|,1)$.